# i need to set a cookie to check if someone attempt wrong login for 5 times

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

i need to set a cookie with unique name so that i need to check whether someone attempts false login for 5 times. each time login fails the cookie value increments and set to database. and checking if that value exceeds 5 then need to block user.
for this i need unique cookie name to store in database.

```
 public function doLogin(Request $request) {
     $ipAddress = GeneralLib::getIPAddress();// getting ip as expeced
     $loginattempt_cookie_name = "checkLogin".$ipAddress;

    if(isset($_COOKIE[$loginattempt_cookie_name])) {
        $loginattempt_cookie_value = $_COOKIE[$loginattempt_cookie_name];
}
else {
 else {
       $loginattempt_cookie_name = "checkLogin".$ipAddress;

       $loginattempt_cookie_value = 1;

       setcookie($loginattempt_cookie_name, $loginattempt_cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
     }
```

but the cookie name is not setting as expected,How can i set a unique cookie?

Comment: With timestamp?

Comment: Why would the cookie name have to be “unique”?

Comment: A session variable would be a better way to do it.

Comment: The user can clear the cookies, so this is not very reliable. Also they could switch to another browser or device to try and defeat it. Better to use session data (would defeat clearing the cookies) and/or store in database, associated with the username (would defeat the switching browser/device tactic, if you care about that). And I suggest storing a timestamp so you can reset the attempt count if the last attempt was some time ago (assuming they didn't reach the max and get blocked. Even then, is the block temporary or permanent? Lots you haven't considered here, I feel.).

Comment: Also, IP address is not a reliable identifier either. You've already got the username, so use that.

Comment: i need to check from whether the attempt is greater than 5 in each time for that i need a condition in where statement i need to take that witth cookie name.
@ ADyson .. i couldn't use username since in first attempt the username as cookie name is stored into table second time i need to check whether this exist in table since username varies i couldn't check this.

Comment: Ok so the feature is slightly different that the normal one...sounds like you actually want to block people who are just trying out any usernames, rather than someone trying a specific username repeatedly. In that case you would log the IP address in the database. Although IP address is not 100% reliable an an identifier, it's better than cookies - that defence is really easy to bypass.

Comment: okay i have stored the ip in the table , Can i use a cookie name as 
$ipAddress = GeneralLib::getIPAddress();// getting ip as expeced
     $loginattempt_cookie_name = "checkLogin".$ipAddress; like checkLogin192.168.0.10

Comment: You could but why? Just store the IP address and the number of attempts in the database. Job done. Not sure why you think cookies are useful here? Like I said, anyone who is genuinely trying to hack your system will find it easy to remove them.

Comment: yes i used that  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; but the issue is that say all the system from my company uses the same ip say 192.168.0.10 its the public ip. if my system is blocked the login attempt from other machine is also get blocked

Comment: That's true. Well you could store the user-agent string alongside it in the database, so you can block a unique combination of the user-agent and the IP. But that only blocks one browser at a time (so the hacker could still move their machine to another network, or just use another browser on the same machine). And user-agent strings can be spoofed just as easily as cookies can be removed, so it still doesn't help against even a moderately-serious hacker.

Comment: Ultimately there is no 100% foolproof way of doing this kind of blocking. It will be like playing whack-a-mole - whenever you squash one attempt, it will just pop up somewhere else instead. And you can end up blocking genuine users as easily as you find malicious ones. Most hacking attempts of this nature are likely to be automated...so why not just use something like a Captcha on the login form, which is designed to defeat automated bots trying to submit data to your server. There are several available, but Google's reCaptcha, as just one example, is very efficient at this task.

Comment: The catpcha stops them from submitting any data at all, if it doesn't believe the user is a human being. And if they try to bypass your form and use automated tools to submit data to the server directly (without a browser) then they cannot ever pass the captcha test, so their entry will always be rejected.